# VARCHAR to DATE in Snowflake

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

Hello I need varchar to date.

**My varchar looks like this:**

- Oct 2, 2020

**This is my desired output:**

- 2020-10-02

**Any ideas? Thanks in advance!**

**Here is the error I get when trying to_date:**

[image]

Comment: Your format string needs to match the format of the input field, not the format you want to display the output in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you should use is `'MON DD, YYYY'`:

```sql
select to_date('Oct 2, 2020', 'MON DD, YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution, @Felipe Hoffa!

Solution:
select to_date('Oct 2, 2020', 'MON DD, YYYY')